# Accumulation points and delta neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

In my complex analysis textbook an accumulation point of a set $S$ is defined as a point which for every deleted delta neighborhood of it that deleted delta neighbourhood will have common points with the set $S$. I am curious why the accumulation points are defined using the deleted delta neighbourhood and not just the delta neighboorhood.It seems to me that using the delta neighborhood for the definition would have the same implications.Am I right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to figure out the difference, if S consists of a single point.

Comment: @Ulli Could you please explain?

Comment: If $S$ includes an "isolated" point $p$, the two definitions give you different results when applied to $p$.  The concept is much more useful if accumulation points are defined in such a way that they don't include isolated points.

Comment: @Kani Pen: if $ S = \{p\} $, $p$ is *not* an accumulation point according to the usual definiton (based upon deleted neighborhoods). Would it be an accumulation point according to your definition?

Comment: @Ulli Yes, it would. Now I understand the difference. Thank you